# How to add jQuery CDN fallback in XHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, cdn, fallback

It is good practice to load a [CDN-hosted jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) but to [fallback to a local file](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fallback-for-cdn-hosted-jquery/). E.g. HTML5 Boilerplate does it like this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

But how can the same be implemented in XHTML? As `document.write()` doesn't work in proper XHTML (sent as `application/xhtml+xml`), is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code creates a new `<script/>` element and appends it before first `<script/>` element on your page:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = 'js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js';

   var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, firstScript);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`createElement`, `setAttribute`, `appendChild` as per usual when replacing `document.write` or `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Maxim Vi.'s reply, I made it closer to the original idea to insert it where it is called:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="jQuery">
if (!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js';
    var jQueryScript = document.getElementById('jQuery');
    jQueryScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, jQueryScript);
}
</script>
```

This way you can keep your scripts in the footer (in case you have other scripts inside the page, it won't get inserted too early or in different locations).

**Edit:** I had problems in some browsers with that solution, but moving the `id="jQuery"` further down solved it. I adjusted the code accordingly.